# Image upload with ajax and php is failing (no error log)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The following code I'm using to upload images is failing for some reason...
Here is the **HTML**

```
<form id="image_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploadImage.php" method="post" name="prof_picture">
    <input id="image1" style="display:none;" name="image" accept="image/jpeg" type="file">
    <input id="image2" value="Submit" type="submit" style="display:none;">
</form>
```

**PHP** (uploadImage.php)

```
include('../sqlconnection.php');
define ("MAX_SIZE","1000");

function getExtension($str)
{
$i = strrpos($str,".");
if (!$i) { return ""; }
$l = strlen($str) - $i;
$ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
return $ext;
}

$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") 
{
    $uploaddir = "profile/uploads"; //Image upload directory

    $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name'][0]);

    echo $filename;

    $size=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][0]);

    echo $filename;
    //Convert extension into a lower case format
    $ext = getExtension($filename);
    $ext = strtolower($ext);
    //File extension check
    if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
    {
    //File size check
    if ($size < (MAX_SIZE*1024))
    { 
    $image_name=time().$filename; 
    echo "<img src='".$uploaddir.$image_name."' class='imgList'>"; 
    $newname=$uploaddir.$image_name; 
    //Moving file to uploads folder
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][0], $newname)) 
    { 
    $time=time(); 
    //Insert upload image files names into user_uploads table
    mysql_query("UPDATE table SET image='$image_name' WHERE id='$user_id'");
    }
    else 
    { 
    echo '<span class="imgList">failed</span>'; } 
    }

    else 
    { 
    echo '<span class="imgList">failed</span>'; 
    } 

    } 

    else 
    { 
    echo '<span class="imgList">failed</span>'; 
    } 

}
```

**JS**

```
$('#image1').on('change', function() {
        $("#image").attr('src',"profile/loading.gif");

        $("#image_upload").ajaxForm({
                        target: '#image'
        }).submit();
});
```

What I know for **sure**:

**1º** The php script is being achieved correctly because I failed part of the code on purpose and attained an error message regarding an internal php error.

**2º** The query is being done correctly (or at least by its syntax).

**3º** The javascript function related to #image is also working.

I only want to upload one image that the user selects (even if he selects 100 other items). But as I said, I don't even get an error message on the log... Any ideas on this one? Thank you very much!

---

**EDIT**

I've changed the code a bit

```
$ext = strtolower($ext);
    if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats)){
        if ($size < (MAX_SIZE*1024)){ 
            $image_name=time().$user_id."--pfi-".$filename;
            $newname=$uploaddir.$image_name;
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname)){
                    mysql_query("UPDATE table SET image='$image_name' WHERE id='$user_id'");
                }else echo '<span class="imgList">This message appears </span>'; 
        }else echo '<span class="imgList">You have exceeded the size limit!</span>';
    }else echo '<span class="imgList">Unknown extension!</span>';
```

For some reason it now stops at `if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname))`. I've var_dump'ed this and it is indeed "false" but I can't get to understand why. Here is var_dump($_FILES):

```
array(1) { ["image"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(21) "060424_hubble_big.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpZYaDkm" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(35641) } }
```

---

**EDIT 2**

> Warning:
>   move_uploaded_file(profile/uploads/1388794617.png):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   profile/uploadProfilePicture.php on line 37
>   Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phppFfoL4' to
>   'profile/uploads/1388794617.png' in
>   profile/uploadProfilePicture.php on line 37

how should I specify $uploaddir or even $newname?

Comment: try `$uploaddir = "profile/uploads/";`

Comment: If isset($_POST) points out for any form submission. It's not much of a problem considering this is the unique form that points to this script so there won't be any other caught in (of course this isn't as secure as it should be, thanks for pointing that out). && you are correct about this too, but I guess and occurred to me at the moment.

Comment: Add a `/` at the end, as Paul mentioned. May very well be the issue. That I've seen happen before, where it wouldn't show an error message, yet didn't upload anything.

Comment: @Paul tried it just now, but isn't indeed. That's an early flaw probably on attempts of debugging.

Comment: And sorry, I deleted my comment in thinking that it didn't make a difference. You're welcome though.

Comment: There is one thing (may not fix it) but in your form, you have `accept="image/jpeg"` yet in your PHP you have the accepted array of file exts. `$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg");` and `style="display:none;"`

Comment: Can you add result of `var_dump($_FILES);` to the question ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yet nothing, tried it now. I think that is used only to specify a file type at particular in the pop-up (All Files/JPEG/etc)

Comment: I suggest then that you try it without the JS and just use the form along with the pure PHP; if it works, then you'll know it's your JS that's failing.

Comment: Actually, scratch that. I just tried it myself and it's definitely your PHP handler's fault and can't pinpoint the "where".

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. Remove all `[0]` in your PHP and it will now work. Those are used for arrays and since you're only using it for single file uploads, is why it failed.

Comment: are you sure about that plugin supports fileUpload?
try [this](http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-form-submit/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

This is what I used. Notice the commented out conditional statements.

```
<?php

// include('../sqlconnection.php');
 define ("MAX_SIZE","1000000000");


function getExtension($str)
{
$i = strrpos($str,".");
if (!$i) { return ""; }
$l = strlen($str) - $i;
$ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
return $ext;
}

$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg");
// if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") 
// {
    $uploaddir = "profile/uploads/"; //Image upload directory

    $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

    echo $filename;

    $size=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

    echo $filename;
    //Convert extension into a lower case format
    $ext = getExtension($filename);
    $ext = strtolower($ext);
    //File extension check
    if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
    {
    //File size check
    if ($size < (MAX_SIZE*1024))
    { 
    $image_name=time().$filename; 
    echo "<img src='".$uploaddir.$image_name."' class='imgList'>"; 
    $newname=$uploaddir.$image_name; 
    //Moving file to uploads folder
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname)) 
    { 
    $time=time(); 
    //Insert upload image files names into user_uploads table
//    mysql_query("UPDATE table SET image='$image_name' WHERE id='$user_id'");
    }
    else 
    { 
    echo '<span class="imgList">failed</span>'; } 
    }

    else 
    { 
    echo '<span class="imgList">failed</span>'; 
    } 

    } 

    else 
    { 
    echo '<span class="imgList">failed</span>'; 
    } 

// }
```

---

### Original answer

Ok, I found the problem. Remove all `[0]` in your PHP and it will now work. Those are used for arrays and since you're only using it for single file uploads, is why it failed.

Sidenote: You may want to add a `/` at the end of `$uploaddir = "profile/uploads";` as in `$uploaddir = "profile/uploads/";`

The following doesn't have the `[0]`'s and have tested it as pure PHP with no JS.

```
include('../sqlconnection.php');
define ("MAX_SIZE","1000");

function getExtension($str)
{
$i = strrpos($str,".");
if (!$i) { return ""; }
$l = strlen($str) - $i;
$ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
return $ext;
}

$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") 
{
    $uploaddir = "profile/uploads"; //Image upload directory

    $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

    echo $filename;

    $size=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

    echo $filename;
    //Convert extension into a lower case format
    $ext = getExtension($filename);
    $ext = strtolower($ext);
    //File extension check
    if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
    {
    //File size check
    if ($size < (MAX_SIZE*1024))
    { 
    $image_name=time().$filename; 
    echo "<img src='".$uploaddir.$image_name."' class='imgList'>"; 
    $newname=$uploaddir.$image_name; 
    //Moving file to uploads folder
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname)) 
    { 
    $time=time(); 
    //Insert upload image files names into user_uploads table
    mysql_query("UPDATE table SET image='$image_name' WHERE id='$user_id'");
    }
    else 
    { 
    echo '<span class="imgList">failed</span>'; } 
    }

    else 
    { 
    echo '<span class="imgList">failed</span>'; 
    } 

    } 

    else 
    { 
    echo '<span class="imgList">failed</span>'; 
    } 

}
```

Comment: It was exactly that!! But unfortunately it doens't upload anyway. Check the edit please and I'll give you the correct answer(it is indeed!)

Comment: I commented out the DB stuff to test it with, so that's the area that could be at fault. @user111671 and if I do recall, I commented out the `if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")` also. I will add to my question exactly what I used, as an edit.

Comment: and did it actually run inside the if? If it goes through every if before the problem with this shouldn't be there... It doens't even reach the query so it's just odd not to work right at the if move_uploaded_files

Comment: Yes, my edit is what I used exactly as shown, I didn't deviate from it. I only commented out what I didn't need (DB) as well as what I thought would be troublesome; the conditional statement `if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")` @user111671

Comment: Another thing I took out were both `style="display:none;"` in the form. I couldn't see the buttons, because you're probably using them in a special manner. @user111671

Comment: I'm almost figuring it out! Now here's the message error that is appearing (in the question edit)

Comment: I saw the edit. That's because you didn't put the `/` in `$uploaddir = "profile/uploads";`at the end @user111671 notice the absence of it in `directory in profile/uploadProfilePicture.php` there's no `/` between the words `upload` and `ProfilePicture` you need the ending slash.

Comment: Ok, well that's really bizarre. Check what your folder permissions are set to. This has to work; I tested it 100%. Is the folder writeable? @user111671

Comment: Oh btw, that is the name of the script, so it is correct. profile/"uploadProfilePicture.php". What I really want is for the folder to be in profile/uploads/pictures/etc... by this I mean, in the same folder of the php script

Comment: You'll need to adjust the setting for your upload folder then. If you're running the script from your root, then using `profile/uploads/pictures/` as the upload setting will work. If you're running it from outside the root, then you'll need to do something like `../profile/uploads/pictures/` @user111671 and make sure the folders exist.